# why should we set the local_infile=1 in sqlalchemy to load local file? Load file not allowed issue in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to connect to MySQL database and found a strange behavior.
If I query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'C:\\\\Temp\\\\JaydenW\\\\iata_processing\\\\icer\\\\rename\\\\ICER_2017-10- 
12T09033
7Z023870.csv
```

It pops an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1148, u'The used 
command is not allowed with this MySQL versi
on') [SQL: u"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'C:\\\\Temp\\\\JaydenW\\\\iata_processing\\\\icer\\\\rename\\\\ICER_2017-10- 
12T090337Z023870.csv' INTO TABLE genie_etl.iata_icer_etl LINES TERMINATED BY 
'\\n' 
IGNORE 1 Lines   (rtxt);"] (Background on this error at: 
http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

And I find the reason is that:
I need to set the parameter as

```
args = "mysql+pymysql://"+username+":"+password+"@"+hostname+"/"+database+"? 
local_infile=1"
```

If I use MySQL official connection library. I do not need to do so.

```
myConnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database)
```

Can anyone help me to understand the difference between the two mechanisms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the mechanisms use different drivers.
In SQLAlchemy you appear to be using the [pymysql engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql), which uses the [PyMySQL Connection class](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html?highlight=local_infile) to create the DB connection. That one requires the user to explicitly pass the `local_infile` parameter if they want to use the `LOAD DATA LOCAL` command.

The other example uses [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), which is basically a wrapper around the MySQL C API (and to my knowledge not the official connection library; that would be [MySQL Connector Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/), which is also available on SQLAlchemy as [mysqlconnector](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqlconnector)). This one apparently creates the connection in a way that the `LOAD DATA LOCAL` is enabled by default.